# Replace with regex keeping part of the pattern

Tags: regex, vbscript

In the example below, how to preserve part of a pattern? The pattern search must include closing tag `</h3>` as spans elsewhere must not be targeted.

Example: remove only `</span>` from `</span> some text </h3>`:

```
regEx.Pattern = "</span>[^>]*</h3>"
hr2 = regEx.Replace(hr2,"[^>]*</h3>")  '<- does not work
```

Comment: Try `regEx.Pattern = "</span>([^>]*)</h3>" // hr2 = regEx.Replace(hr2,"$1</h3>")`

Comment: This did the same as what did not work above - passed it through, in this case as '$1'.

Comment: Sorry, your solution correct. Did not notice the brackets in the pattern above that make $1 work. Thanks for fast help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a capturing group and use a back reference in the replacement pattern.

```
regEx.Pattern = "</span>([^>]*)</h3>"
hr2 = regEx.Replace(hr2,"$1</h3>")
```

Or

```
regEx.Pattern = "</span>([^>]*</h3>)"
hr2 = regEx.Replace(hr2,"$1")
```

Comment: It may be worth considering using the non-greedy expression `.*?` instead of `[^>]*` in case there are other tags between `</span>` and `</h3>`.

Comment: Yes, but we do not know the input text. Surely `.*?` will also capture the tags before `</h3>` then.

Comment: `</span>(.*?)</h3>` would capture tags between `</span>` and `</h3>`, yes.